# Ошибка в AIDE: This method must return the value of type

Tags: android, tablet, aide

При создании чистого проекта в AIDE на планшете 4.2.2 создаётся базовый код, в котором само приложение находит ошибку

> This method must return the value of type "

И предлагает исправить ее путём добавления 'return 0' перед предпоследней скобкой, что в свою очередь влечёт опять же ошибку

> A void method can not return a value

И предлагает убрать цифру 0. Приложение компилируется, но не запускается, ссылаясь на ошибку в приложении... Какие у кого идеи, что это может быть? Версии AIDE пробовал разные.

Comment: код показали бы.

Comment: package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.app.*;

import android.os.*;

import android.view.*;

import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

  return 0;
 }

}

Comment: Это уже с первым исправлением quickfix

Comment: No error, если оставить 'return;'

Comment: Сейчас попробовал установить на смартфон (тоже 4.2.2) - на нем все работает и при создании нового проекта никаких намеков на ошибки нет! Планшет Wexler Tab7T.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибок-то в коде нет, это AIDE так реагирует на пиратство)
Я так понимаю, что вы скачали AIDE [отсюда](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?s=&showtopic=319369&view=findpost&p=30976318) или просто не так пропатчили. Пробуйте установить [вот отсюда](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=319369&st=960#entry31294175), и всё заработает.

Comment: Начинал ставить с версии на маркете, потом уже пробовать и с пиратскими и с патчами - какие удавалось найти. Сейчас попробую Ваш вариант :-)

Comment: Не забудьте удалить старую версию (и /sdcard/.aide, там хранятся данные о состояниях приложения), перед тем, как установить новую.

Comment: Аааа! Работает! Огромное человеческое спасибо! Даже и не знаю, чем отблагодарить! Гранд респект!!!

Comment: Самое интересное, что та же версия глючная прекрасно работает на смарте!

Comment: @mephdm, если я вам помог, то отметьте мой ответ как правильный (ну и "палец вверх" можно нажать).

Comment: Говорит, что у меня недостаточно очков для этого действия :-(

Comment: каким же мазохистом надо быть чтобы в AIDE чтото пытаться писать... тем более java... был бы 1С я бы понял

Comment: Предлагаю ввести тег "мазохизм")